# r easy nxn covariance matrix creation with given variances and covariances

Tags: r, matrix

For a simulation study I need to create nxn covariance matrices. for example I can input 2x2 covariance matrices like

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1.0  1.5
[2,] 1.5  2.0
```

into a r function/object:

```
var <- c(1,2) ## variances
covar <- c(1.5,1.5) ## covariance(s)
mat <- matrix(c(var[1],covar[1],covar[2],var[2]),ncol=length(var))
```

then I only have to change `var` & `covar` values to form the matrices. but unfortunately I'm not just dealing with 2x2s but 2x2:30x30 or even higher! so is it possible to write only one function for any matrix of nxn dimension in r?

Comment: so your question is: you have a vector of variance of size n, a vector of covariance of size n*(n-1) and you wanna build youir n*n matrix?

Comment: what is the order of the covar vector? (this matters to build the matrix...)

Comment: and by the way do not call a vector `var` but `variance` for example, `var` is a name of a function ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
m <- diag(variance)
m[lower.tri(m)] = m[upper.tri(m)] <- head(covar, length(covar)/2)
```

For example:

```
variance = c(0.25, 0.75, 0.6)
covar = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2)

#>m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.25 0.10  0.3
#[2,] 0.10 0.75  0.2
#[3,] 0.30 0.20  0.6
```

Comment: @SlightlyBuilt you can also upvote, that would be another +10 :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel I think your answer should be `m=diag(variance) ; m[lower.tri(m)]=head(covar, length(covar)/2) ; m[upper.tri(m)]=t(m)[upper.tri(m)]` and needs editing.

Comment: @SlightlyBuilt. No, with the data I provided it works fine. Of course if you take as data `covar=c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1)` you need your solution. This is why it is extremely important to provide relevant data when you ask a question (which was not done and I had to introduce some)